# How to call gwt servlet from native java?

Tags: java, gwt, rpc, gwt-rpc, gwt-syncproxy

GWT code is a part of UI as an iframe. Now when the page is logged out, It should somehow call the gwt servlet code in the background and to invalidate the session. I have tried syncproxy, gwtrpccommlayer, But it didnt work since objects for the clients cant be created since it doesnt come under the gwt lifecycle.

Please suggest me how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "...when the page is logged out".  When a true log out happens, the session should be cleared then.

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding your issue correctly. What backend are you using? What purpose are you trying to use syncproxy/rpccommlayer for in terms of session management?